# dynamically bind .on() method with event-map

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

I'm using this syntax to make sure that the events bind on dynamically added `li` elements

```
$('ul.list').on('click', 'li', function() {

   //do something

});
```

I tried to archive the same with an event-map like this:

```
$('ul.list').hammer({
    css_hacks : false
}).on({
     swipe : function(event){
        //do something
     },
     doubletap : function(event){
        //some more code
     }
}, 'li');
```

but its not working at all.
If I bind the events directly to the `li` element it works fine for existing elements, but not for dynamically added elements.

```
$('ul.list').find('li').hammer({
    css_hacks : false
}).on({
     swipe : function(event){
        //do something
     },
     doubletap : function(event){
        //some more code
     }
});
```

How to bind the event-map to future elements?

Comment: The first method should work. jQuery's `on()` method is recommended over `live()` and `bind()`

Comment: agreed @Silasj - bug in on?

Comment: I did a little playing around with this and it appears it might be a bug in on a @Paul suggests. The next best solution is to chain the .on() events: .on('swipe','li',function).on('doubletap','li',function)

Comment: if hammer plugin isn't written to return element and allow chaining, try reversing `on()` and `hammer()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on()` with 2 parameters is eqvivalent to the old `bind()` functionality.

If you want to make it work like `live()` did, pass a third argument like in your first example.

Also, if your'e having trouble when chaining functions on the `hammer()` method, inspect it and make sure that it returns "this".

```
$('ul.list').on({
    swipe : function() { ... },
    doubletap : function() { ... }
},'li');
```

Comment: I had to include **jquery.specialevent.hammer.js** to have delegation support. The default jquery.hammer.js doesn't support `live() ; on()`

Answer (score 0):

if you look into jquery document,[jquery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

it says,**Chaining methods is not supported. For example, $("a").find(".offsite, .external").live( ... ); is not valid and does not work as expected.**

so you can do this:

```
$('ul.list > li').hammer({
    css_hacks : false
}).live({
     swipe : function(event){
        //do something
     },
     doubletap : function(event){
        //some more code
     }
});
```

but it's deprecated, I think your first example should work.

I tried this:

```
<ul>
<li>aaa</li>
<li>bbb</li>
</ul>
```

and

```
$("ul").on({
    click:function(){
        $(this).html('clicked');
        },
    dblclick:function(){
        $(this).html('double clicked');
        }
    },'li');
```

it works, so i guess your problem may be the name of event.

Comment: the name of the events come from hammer.js. My last example works fine with those names.