# Hammer.js events on dynamically added HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div id="snaps">
    <div class="snap_item">
        <div class="snap_item_following_info">
            <img class="snap_item_following_img" src="res/stat/img/user/profile/small/1.fw.png" alt="@JohnDoe" />
            <a class="snap_item_following_name" href="#">@JohnDoe</a>
        </div>
        <img class="snap_img" src="res/stat/img/user/snap/43/2.fw.png" alt="@ErolSimsir" />
        <div class="like_heart"></div>
        <div class="snap_info">
            <div class="snap_text">
                Image caption
                    <a class="snap_text_hashtah" href="@">#LA_city_trip</a>
            </div>
            <div class="snap_sub_info">
                <span class="snap_time">56 minutes ago</span>
                <div class="like inactive_like">
                    <div class="like_icon"></div>
                    <div class="like_no_active">5477</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The div '#snaps' is a static div, which holds all the '.snap_item' elements which are added with the JQuery .html() function. So the '.snap_item' elements are dynamically added to the div '#snaps', like so:

```
<div id="snaps"><!-- static div that holds the dynamic elements -->
    <div class="snap_item"><!-- dynamically added element -->
        <img class="snap_img" src="..." alt="..." /><!-- when this element is double tapped, the event should be fired -->
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user double taps on '.snap_img', some stuff has to happen. The element '.snap_img' is inside the '.snap_item' element.

What I have so far is:

```
$('#snaps').find('.snap_item').hammer().on({
     doubletap : function(event){
        alert("doubletap!");
     }
});
```

This doesn't work at all. The on() function should allow me to fire events on dynamically added HTML, but this code doesn't work. I have this code from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810137/dynamically-bind-on-method-with-event-map%E2%80%8F)

I have included hammer.js, jquery_hammer_plugin.js and query.specialevent.hammer.js. So all the necessary JS files have been included, but still no luck.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so I've solved the issue by using this code:

```
$('#snaps').hammer({domEvents:true}).on("doubletap", ".snap_img", function() {
    alert("doubletap!"); 
});
```

So, whoever is having an issue with firing Hammer touch events on dynamically added HTML, this is the solution!!!

Thanks to everyone who (tried) to help! :)

Comment: I'm getting error after writing this code `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hammer is not a function`

Comment: me too.  not a function.